# Нужны ли знаки по меткам за вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, знаки

Увидел соответствующий [вопрос на codegolf'е](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8118/32091), в [комментарии](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/count-question-score-toward-tag-badges#comment22287_8118) и которому [Alex A. ♦](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a) говорит, что такая функциональность может быть добавлена только ко всем сайтам сети.

У меня возникла мысль, что хорошие вопросы ценятся на всех сайтах. В принципе, за вопросы уже есть три знака, которые относятся к общему числу вопросов. А почему бы действительно не добавить знаки к вопросам по метке?

Comment: а как их отличать от меток за ответы?

Comment: @Grundy, надо что-нибудь придумать :)

Comment: Кину сюда ещё одно предложение по новым значкам: [Нужны знаки за места в чартах](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1633/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85?rq=1)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб всё-таки зря отклонили предложение про VlaD, было бы интересно на это посмотреть.

Comment: @Vartlok, вот-вот) Никакой поддержки соревновательного духа)))